# c++ writing a programm about reading from a text file and printing the whole sentence that include specific words

Tags: string

i am slightly rusty on programming and i was asked to write a c++ program that would read and print from a text file whole lines that include one, both or none of the words given by the user.

this is what i have until now

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string string1,string2;
ifstream in_stream;
char choice;

void main()
{

//oppening the file needed
in_stream.open("file.txt");

//giving the strings to search
cout << "Give two strings. " << endl;
cin >> string1;
cin >> string2;

// choosing which mode to follow
cout << "Choose which mode you prefer: " << endl;
cout << "A: Both words in each line." << endl;
cout << "B: One of the words in each line." << endl;
cout << "C: None of the words in each line." << endl;
cin >> choice;


switch (choice)
{
case 'A': cout << choice << endl;
    break;

case 'B': cout << choice << endl;
    break;

case 'C': cout << choice << endl;
    break;

default: cout << "Incorrect choice" << endl;
    break;
}
system ("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string string1,string2;
ifstream in_stream;
char choice;

void printLine(const vector<string>& _line)
{
    for (const auto& word : _line)
        cout << word << " ";

    cout << endl;
}

void main()
{
    //oppening the file needed
    in_stream.open("file.txt");

    vector<vector<string> > lines;
    lines.push_back(vector<string>());
    while (in_stream.good())
    {
        string1.clear();
        in_stream >> string1;
        if (!string1.empty())
            lines.back().push_back(string1);

        if (in_stream.good())
        {
            if (in_stream.peek() == '\n')
                lines.push_back(vector<string>());
        }
    }

    //giving the strings to search
    cout << "Give two strings. " << endl;
    cin >> string1;
    cin >> string2;

    // choosing which mode to follow
    cout << "Choose which mode you prefer: " << endl;
    cout << "A: Both words in each line." << endl;
    cout << "B: One of the words in each line." << endl;
    cout << "C: None of the words in each line." << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 'A': cout << choice << endl;
        for (const auto& line : lines)
        {
            if (find(line.begin(), line.end(), string1) != line.end() && find(line.begin(), line.end(), string2) != line.end())
                printLine(line);
        }
        break;

    case 'B': cout << choice << endl;
        for (const auto& line : lines)
        {
            if (find(line.begin(), line.end(), string1) != line.end() || find(line.begin(), line.end(), string2) != line.end())
                printLine(line);
        }
        break;

    case 'C': cout << choice << endl;
        for (const auto& line : lines)
        {
            if (find(line.begin(), line.end(), string1) == line.end() && find(line.begin(), line.end(), string2) == line.end())
                printLine(line);
        }
        break;

    default: cout << "Incorrect choice" << endl;
        break;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```